# How can I do cases in plain text mode?

Tags: cases

I am trying to draw `cases` as in the attached picture. Is there any way to draw one in plain text mode? If not possible, is there any way to put `y variables` at the bottom of the leftmost brace?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: You could just use \text.  Or is that not what you had in mind?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \[
\begin{dcases*}
    x & variables  \\
    y & variables
    \smash{$\begin{dcases*}
      a & variables  \\
      n & variables
    \end{dcases*}$}
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variant is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \[
\begin{dcases*}
    x & variables  \\
    y & variables
    \smash[b]{$\begin{dcases*}
      a & variables  \\
      n & variables
    \end{dcases*}$}
\end{dcases*}
\]

\medskip  %% add a blank line and \medskip
Some text comes here for demo Some text comes here for demo Some text comes here for demo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since we have used `\smash`, the content that comes after this display math may collide with each other as noted by Mico. It is better to add some vertical space  after this by using, say, `\medskip` as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\space}l@{\space}l@{\space}l}
\ldelim\{{3}{10pt} & x variable  \\
                   &             & \ldelim\{{3}{10pt} & a variables \\
                   & y variables \\
                   &             &                    & b variables
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```